# "in Starbucks at the mall" OR "at Starbucks in the mall"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

Which one is correct in terms of the combination of two locations.

> You work in Starbucks at the mall
>
> You work at Starbucks in the mall
>
> You work in Starbucks in the mall
>
> You work at Starbucks at the mall

What is the rule behind the usage of *at* and *in* for this specific context?

Comment: Either, though "at" is likely more common.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be correct.

*At the mall* implies the mall is a particular location. This fits.

*In the mall* implies the mall is an enclosure or building. Even an outdoor mall with no roof roughly fits the "enclosure* definition.

Comment: To further elaborate, at some malls, there may be some free-standing buildings outside the main building (e.g. gas stations). In such a case, the business is "at the mall," but not "in the mall."  If the business is inside the mall, it is both "in" and "at the mall."

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more natural to say "at Starbucks in the mall." That would use *mall* to refer to an indoor shopping center. An outdoor strip mall that was locally referred to as a *mall* might change the answer to "at the mall." A Starbucks hypothetically located alongside the lawn between the Washington Monument and the Capitol Building in Washington, D.C. would require "on the Mall," although the only buildings there are museums.